# KnockoutJS: Tracking menu clicks

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have just started playing with KnockoutJS and it it fascinating. I successfully created some templates to render two panels of an interface with "ul" nested menus inside.

Here are my templates:

```
<script id="menuItemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li class='${ Class }' >
        <a class='${ Class }' data-bind='click: function() { viewModel.menuClicked(Id); }'>${ Name }</a>
        <ul class='${ Class }' data-bind='template: { name: "menuItemTemplate", foreach: Items }'></ul>
    <li>
</script>
<script id="menuTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul class='${ Class }' data-bind='template: { name: "menuItemTemplate", foreach: Items }'></ul>
</script>
<script id="consoleTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class='${ Class }' data-bind='template: { name: "menuTemplate", data: Menu }'></div>
</script>
<h2>Application Administration</h2>
<div id="console" class="console" data-bind='template: { name: "consoleTemplate", foreach: Panels }'>
</div>
```

And here is the simplified code for my view model:

```
$(function () {
var viewModel = {
    "Panels": [
        {
        "Id" : 1,
        "Class": "main",
        "Menu": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Class": "file",
            "Name": "File",
            "Items": [{
                "Id": 1,
                "Class": "open",
                "Name": "Open",
                "Items": []
            }]
        }
    }]
};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'console.asmx/Initialize',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            viewModel = data.d;
            viewModel.menuActive = ko.observable(false);
            viewModel.currentMenu = ko.observable(0);
            viewModel.menuClicked = function (id) {
                viewModel.menuActive(true);
                viewModel.currentMenu(id);
            };
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
});
```

So far, the panels and the menus are rendered fine but I now need to know which menu was clicked and show the sub-menu as well as other UI elements based on the clicked menu. The function I attached to the hyperlinks is throwing an exception: `'Uncaught ReferenceError: viewModel is not defined'` when I click on any of the hyperlinks.

I also tried to bind the visibility of sub-menus to the "currentMenu" property of the viewModel but that broke everything:

```
<script id="menuItemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li class='${ Class }' data-bind='visible: viewModel.menuActive && viewModel.currentMenu == Id'>
        <a class='${ Class }' data-bind='click: function() { viewModel.menuClicked(Id); }'>${ Name }</a>
        <ul class='${ Class }' data-bind='template: { name: "menuItemTemplate", foreach: Items }'></ul>
    <li>
</script>
```

How can I properly bind the click event handler as well as the visibility based on the clicked menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that your variable viewModel is defined in the jQuery ready function, so the functions in your data-binds can't see it, since it is not at the global scope.  Even, doing a `var viewModel = {}` outside the `$(function() { ... });` would work.

The way that you defined your click function looks good to me.  Your visible logic though should use `viewModel.menuActive()` and `viewModel.currentMenu()` to access the values as they are in an expression.

Hope this helps.  Would be happy to help further, if you get stuck.

Comment: One more question: Currently my visible logic only  displays the child of the clicked menu by checking the `currentMenu` property. I need a way to display the complete hierarchy (parent, grandParent, etc) in which the clicked menu belongs to. Is there a "knockout" way of doing this?

Comment: Probably several ways to tackle that one.  I would likely add a dependentObservable to each item that would return true if it is the selected menu or if any of its children are the selected menu.  I would imagine this would perform fine for any smaller set of menus.  If performance was a concern, then you might need to have a reference to the parent from the children, have the currentMenu store the item itself, then when clicked you could first deactive the old menu and then activate the new one.