# KnockoutJS: Converting an array to observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

This question build up on [KnockoutJS: Tracking menu clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291152/knockoutjs-tracking-menu-clicks/5291309) and [KnockoutJS: Event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292197/knockoutjs-event-object/5292678).
I have re-factored the code a bit to seperate the viewModel and the UI logic. What I'm trying to do now is convert the "Children" object array of each "Menu" object into an observableArray so I can add/remove a menu's children to change my UI.

Here is my simplified code:

```
var viewModel = {};
var viewContext = {
    initialize: function (data) {
        viewModel = data;

        //for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.Panels.length; i++) {
            viewContext.observe(viewModel.Panels[0].Menu);
        //}
        viewModel.menuActive = ko.observable(false);
        viewModel.currentMenu = ko.observable(0);
        viewModel.currentNode = ko.observable({});
        viewModel.currentList = ko.observableArray([])
    },
    observe: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Children.length; i++) {
            viewContext.observe(data.Children[i]);
        }
        data.Children = ko.observableArray(data.Children);
    },
    nodeClicked: function (event) {
        var target = $(event.target)
        var data = target.tmplItem().data

        viewContext.getData(data, function (response) {
            viewModel.currentList(response.d);
            data.Children(response.d);
        });
        viewModel.currentNode(data);
    },
    getData: function (data, onSuccess) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'console.asmx/' + data.Method,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: ko.utils.stringifyJson(data),
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSuccess,
            error: function () {
                viewModel.currentList([]);
            }
        });
    }
};
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'console.asmx/Initialize',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            viewContext.initialize(data.d);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
});
```

When the page is initially rendered (using the templates in the referenced questions), everything is fine. However, when I click on a menu which is fires the "nodeClicked" event, I get an error on the line `data.Children(response.d);` that says **"Uncaught ReferenceError: Children is not defined"**.

My guess is that the line `data.Children = ko.observableArray(data.Children);` is not converting my array properly into an observableArray.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `data.Children` defined when `ko.observableArray(data.Children)` is called?

Comment: yes it is. The data comes from the server after an ajax call, and every menu object has a property "Children" which is an array (empty if it is a leaf object). I can confirm this because my UI is rendered correctly for elements bound to data.Children.

Comment: It is fine to create an observableArray from an array with the syntax that you are using.  It should not cause a problem.  I would try logging data and response.d in your callback from your AJAX request to make sure that they are what you expect.  Some console.log calls if you are using Firefox with Firebug or Chrome would probably help.  Otherwise, even some alert(ko.toJSON(data)) in the callback would hopefully show something.  Maybe add it to the question.  Your application is a bit too involved for someone else to easily work up a jsFiddle to simulate it.  Maybe you could try.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks RP! I think you just pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer, you were right! My ajax response was returning an object which did not have a "Children" property at some point. How can I give you credit for this suggestion? Can your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to create an observableArray from an array with the syntax that you are using. It should not cause a problem. I would try logging data and response.d in your callback from your AJAX request to make sure that they are what you expect. Some console.log calls if you are using Firefox with Firebug or Chrome would probably help. Otherwise, even some alert(ko.toJSON(data)) in the callback would hopefully show something.  If it is saying Children is not defined, then it is more than a problem with moving it from a normal array to an observableArray as Chidren is not there at all.

Here's a snippet of what will and will not work:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/getMoreData", function (allData) {
  if (allData) {
    var mappedData = $.map(allData.rows, function (row) {
      return new Object();
    });

    // DOES NOT WORK:
    //self.koArray().unshift(mappedData);

    // DOES WORK!
    for (var i = 0; i < mappedData.length; i++) {
      self.koArray().unshift(mappedData[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a quick comment - I needed to dynamically grab more data using our REST interface and then append that data to our knockout table. I had to loop through the array and add the items individually rather than adding the entire array in order for Knockout to not complain. Thanks RP.